# How to connect MS sql using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

Im trying to implement this node code to connect to database from script.js. Im getting error that require is undefined. i think i installed all npms... This is problematic part of the code:

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

// Create connection to database
var config = {
  server: '127.0.0.1', 
  authentication: {
      type: 'default',
      options: {
          userName:'sa',
          password:'qwertz12'
      }
  },
  options: {
      database: 'variables_DB',
      port:50632
  }
}
```

This is my full code:

```
// Ucitaj google-ov API za crtanje grafa
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
var numbersFromLabView1 = [];
var numbersFromLabView2 = [];
var numbersFromLabView3 = [];
var numbersFromLabView4 = [];
var numbersFromLabView5 = [];
var numbersFromLabView6 = [];
var numbersFromLabView7 = [];
var numbersFromLabView8 = [];
var arrayFromLabView = [];

var time = [];

// na click bottuna
$('.viewbutton').click(function() {
  // Zovi api poziv i dohvati podatke svako 2 sec
  $('#portfolio').addClass('hidden');
  $('#element-di-zivi-aplikacija').removeClass('hidden');
  setInterval(getDataFromLabView, 2000);


});


var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

// Create connection to database
var config = {
  server: '127.0.0.1', 
  authentication: {
      type: 'default',
      options: {
          userName:'sa',
          password:'qwertz12'
      }
  },
  options: {
      database: 'variables_DB',
      port:50632
  }
}
var connection = new Connection(config);

// Attempt to connect and execute queries if connection goes through
connection.on('connect', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected');
  }
});

function getDataFromLabView() {





  var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: 'Slanje_varijabli_HTTP',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (jsonArray) {


      var zadnjiBroj   = jsonArray[0];
      var zadnjiBrojy  = jsonArray[1];
      var zadnjiBrojz  = jsonArray[2];
      var zadnjiBrojxa = jsonArray[3];
      var zadnjiBrojya = jsonArray[4];
      var zadnjiBrojza = jsonArray[5];
      var zadnjiBrojxb = jsonArray[6];
      var zadnjiBrojyb = jsonArray[7];



      drawChart(
      zadnjiBroj,
      zadnjiBrojy,
      zadnjiBrojz,
      zadnjiBrojxa,
      zadnjiBrojya,
      zadnjiBrojza,
      zadnjiBrojxb,
      zadnjiBrojyb);


      $(document.querySelector('.current-number'))  .text(zadnjiBroj);
      $(document.querySelector('.current-numbery')) .text(zadnjiBrojy);
      $(document.querySelector('.current-numberz')) .text(zadnjiBrojz);
      $(document.querySelector('.current-numberxa')).text(zadnjiBrojxa);
      $(document.querySelector('.current-numberya')).text(zadnjiBrojya);
      $(document.querySelector('.current-numberza')).text(zadnjiBrojza);
      $(document.querySelector('.current-numberxb')).text(zadnjiBrojxb);
      $(document.querySelector('.current-numberyb')).text(zadnjiBrojyb); 
    }
  });
  }


function drawChart(zadnjiBroj, zadnjiBrojy ,zadnjiBrojz, zadnjiBrojxa, zadnjiBrojya, zadnjiBrojza, zadnjiBrojxb, zadnjiBrojyb) {
  var data1  = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        moment.locale('hr'); 
        time.push(moment());
        numbersFromLabView1.push(zadnjiBroj);
        data1.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
        data1.addColumn('number', 'struja 1');
        numbersFromLabView1.forEach((zadnjiBroj, key) =>  {
        data1.addRow([time[key].format('LTS'), zadnjiBroj]);


    });
  var data2  = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        moment.locale('hr'); 
        time.push(moment());
        numbersFromLabView2.push(zadnjiBrojy );
        data2.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
        data2.addColumn('number', 'struja 2');
        numbersFromLabView2.forEach((zadnjiBrojy, key) =>  {
        data2.addRow([time[key].format('LTS'), zadnjiBrojy]);

        });

  var data3  = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        moment.locale('hr'); 
        time.push(moment());
        numbersFromLabView3.push(zadnjiBrojz );
        data3.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
        data3.addColumn('number', 'struja 3');
        numbersFromLabView3.forEach((zadnjiBrojz, key) =>  {
        data3.addRow([time[key].format('LTS'), zadnjiBrojz]);

        });
  var data4  = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        moment.locale('hr'); 
        time.push(moment());
        numbersFromLabView4.push(zadnjiBrojxa );
        data4.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
        data4.addColumn('number', 'napon 1');
        numbersFromLabView4.forEach((zadnjiBrojxa, key) =>  {
        data4.addRow([time[key].format('LTS'), zadnjiBrojxa]);

        });
  var data5  = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        moment.locale('hr'); 
        time.push(moment());
        numbersFromLabView5.push(zadnjiBrojya );
        data5.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
        data5.addColumn('number', 'napon 2');
        numbersFromLabView5.forEach((zadnjiBrojya, key) =>  {
        data5.addRow([time[key].format('LTS'), zadnjiBrojya]);

        });
  var data6  = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        moment.locale('hr'); 
        time.push(moment());
        numbersFromLabView6.push(zadnjiBrojza );
        data6.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
        data6.addColumn('number', 'napon 3');
        numbersFromLabView6.forEach((zadnjiBrojza, key) =>  {
        data6.addRow([time[key].format('LTS'), zadnjiBrojza]);

        });
  var data7  = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        moment.locale('hr'); 
        time.push(moment());
        numbersFromLabView7.push(zadnjiBrojxb );
        data7.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
        data7.addColumn('number', 'snaga');
        numbersFromLabView7.forEach((zadnjiBrojxb, key) =>  {
        data7.addRow([time[key].format('LTS'), zadnjiBrojxb]);

        });
  var data8  = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        moment.locale('hr'); 
        time.push(moment());
        numbersFromLabView8.push(zadnjiBrojyb );
        data8.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
        data8.addColumn('number', 'frekvencija');
        numbersFromLabView8.forEach((zadnjiBrojyb, key) =>  {
        data8.addRow([time[key].format('LTS'), zadnjiBrojyb]);

        });     

 // chart1
var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
var joinedData2 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData, data3, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1, 2], [1]);

// chart2
var joinedData3 = google.visualization.data.join(data4, data5, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
var joinedData4 = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData3, data6, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1, 2], [1]);

  // stilovi i izgled grafa se ovdje definiraju
  var options = {
    background: 'transparent',
    title: 'Vrijednosti varijabli očitanih iz LabView-a',
    height: 350,
    width: '48%',
    interpolateNulls: true,
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Vrijeme',
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Amplituda',


    }
  }

  // gdje cemo ubaciti char. U ovom slucaju unutar div elementa koji ima ID = chart_div
  var chart  = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
  var chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div2'));
  var chart3 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div3'));
  var chart4 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div4'));

  // nacrtaj graf. Kao parametre saljemo podatke i stilove
       chart.draw(joinedData2, options);
       chart2.draw(joinedData4, options);
       chart3.draw(data7, options);
       chart4.draw(data8, options);
}
```

Comment: You seem to be running this script in the context of a web page? You probably can't and in any case shouldn't be trying to connect to SQL Server directly from a web page, instead it should talk to the HTTP server, which should talk to the database.